# Selenium - Java - Sendkeys not working in textfield. No error

Tags: html, selenium, sendkeys, pageobjects

I am using Selenium using Java in Eclipse environment to automate testcases on website. This is for personal learning.
Following is the html code.

[image]

I am using Page Object Model in Maven project. When I try to use sendkeys method on the textfield it does not work. There is no error. The testcase passes successfully. But text is not typed in the textfield. I tried clicking on the textfield before entering text. It does click but it does not type anything. What could be the problem. Selenium Version - 3.141. Eclipse version - 4.7. Following is the code in my Page file

```
package seleniumeasy.qa.Page;

import org.openqa.selenium.By;
import org.openqa.selenium.Keys;
import org.openqa.selenium.WebElement;
import org.openqa.selenium.support.FindBy;
import org.openqa.selenium.support.PageFactory;

import seleniumeasy.qa.Base.Base;

public class tblDataSearchPage extends Base{

    @FindBy(xpath="//div[@class='panel-body']/input")
    WebElement txtSearch;
    
    public tblDataSearchPage()
    {
        PageFactory.initElements(driver, this);
    }
    
    public void searchElement()
    {
        //txtSearch.click();
        txtSearch.clear();
        txtSearch.sendKeys("smith");
        txtSearch.sendKeys(Keys.RETURN);
                
    }
}
```

Following is my test class

```
package seleniumeasy.test.Tests;

import org.testng.annotations.Test;
import org.testng.asserts.SoftAssert;

import seleniumeasy.qa.Base.Base;
import seleniumeasy.qa.Page.tblDataSearchPage;
import seleniumeasy.qa.Page.tblPaginationPage;

public class tblDataSearchTest extends Base
{

    SoftAssert sAssert;
    tblPaginationPage tObj;
    tblDataSearchPage obj;
    
    public tblDataSearchTest()
    {
        Init();
        sAssert = new SoftAssert();
        tObj=new tblPaginationPage();
        obj = tObj.clickTableDataSearchMenu();      
    }
    @Test
    public void verifySearchElement()
    {
        obj.searchElement();
    }
    /*@Test
    public void verifySearchElementBasedOnUsername()
    {
        boolean bTestPass = obj.searchFilterName();
        
        
    }*/
}
```

Comment: please add you test classs

Comment: added test class

Comment: on further investigation, this seems to be a problem only with chrome driver. In firefox it is working fine.

Comment: Now I downloaded the latest chromedriver (87.0.4280.88) and ran the program still the same problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
txtSearch.click()
WebElement currentElement = driver.switchTo().activeElement();
currentElement.sendKeys("something")
```

Could you try this

Comment: @Jay could you accept the answer also by clicking the tick sign